# Return empty string on error for a sequence of statements

Tags: python, exception, runtime-error, execution

Many a times I have a situation where individual statements like below can throw an exception which I dont care about , in the case of exception it should just return an empty string:

```
name="".join(b.find(itemprop='name').contents)
phone= "".join(b.find(itemprop='telephone').contents)
fax="".join(b.find(itemprop='faxNumber').contents)
```

instead of running all statements , if the first statement causes exception than the whole execution is stopped, eg:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'
```

So without using try catch finally for such long list of statements , how can I ensure that I just run all the statements as above forcefully? there are many dozens of sequential statements to run hence dont want to use try catch construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative similar to @jbaiter's solution is to use a local function. This avoids having to pass an extra argument, producing slightly more readable code.

You can also avoid the use of exceptions in the first place:

```
def find_field(name):
    x= b.find(itemprop=name)
    return "".join(x.contents) if hasattr(x,'contents') else ""

name, phone, fax = map(find_field, ['name','phone','fax'])
```

Comment: You won't get an error complaining about `NoneType`, since it's doing an `if x` check before attempting to access x.contents. If `find` can return an object that isn't None and doesn't have a `contents` attribute, then it could still raise an error, although your question doesn't mention whether this is possible.

Comment: @Ali adding to what @Kevin said, you can explicitly test `if not x is None`, and check `hasattr(x,contents)`, if it's what you want

Comment: I did say no possiblity of an exception, to forcefully run each statement without caring about it at all. Yes in my case content too may not exist.

Comment: @goncalopp good thats a nice solution , please update the code above.

Comment: No test for "if not x is None" ? hasattr takes care of that?

Comment: @Ali yes. the `getattr` suggestion by @jonrsharpe is even cleaner, since you don't need to repeat "contents"

Comment: Yes, `hasattr` will handle the `None` case. You can experiment with this yourself; `hasattr(None, "contents")` produces `False`, rather than crashing.

Answer (score 2):

Try to abstract the individual statements into a single function and put the `try...catch` inside of it:

```
def find_field(name, b):
    try:
        return "".join(b.find(itemprop=name).contents)
    except AttributeError:
        return ""

name = find_field('name', b)
phone = find_field('phone', b)
fax = find_field('fax', b)
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method is to use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
name = "".join(getattr(b.find(itemprop="name"), "contents", ""))
```

The `default` argument to `getattr` (`""`, in this case) is returned if the `object` (`b.find(...)`) doesn't have an attribute `name` (`"contents"`).

You can still reduce the duplication by making this a function:

```
def find_field(item, prop):
    return "".join(getattr(item.find(itemprop=prop), "contents", ""))


name = find_field(b, 'name')
```

---

As Jon Clements points out, one benefit of `getattr` over `try`/`except` is that if `b.find(...)` raises an `AttributeError` (i.e. `b` isn't what you think it is, likely a genuine error), the error will still be thrown. You could adapt this into `try`/`except` using:

```
item = b.find(itemprop="name")
try:
    name = "".join(item.contents)
except AttributeError:
    name = ""
```

Comment: you mean `...  doesn't have an attribute contents`

Comment: I'd posted `getattr` as an option not realising you'd already done so. What I was going to add is that by using this approach it leaves the `AttributeError` open to being thrown on the `b.find` which could be desirable as the object should probably always support that method (hence a genuine error if not), but if it doesn't return `.contents` then no-one cares... Otherwise, the complete try/except approaches suggested by others is probably the way to go.

Comment: @JonClements that's a great point, I will add that into my answer

Comment: what if even b fails to have the find method, can I use something like getattr(b,find....). (To completely avoid try catch..)